# Interpreting log odds in case of multiple predictor variables

Tags: logistic-regression, logistic

Interpretation of log odds with a single predictor variable -->

0.8=2.5(Hypertension)
The odds of a person with hypertension getting heart disease is 0.8.

Log odds with multiple predictor variables -->
0.8=2.5(Hypertension)+0.3(Gender)+0.06(Age)+15

How do I interpret the log odds when the predictor variables are multiple?

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/interpreting-expb-in-multinomial-logistic-regression) of which I cannot improve. The question is for multinomial but the answers starts with multivariate.

To quote the answers - a one-unit change in the variable corresponding to each beta will multiply the relative risk of the outcome. Each coefficient is the marginal change in log odds with respect to the variable.