# Checking the interpretation of log odds in logistic regression (with multiple variables)

Tags: logistic-regression, odds

Here's a log odds equation -->

**0.8=2.5(Hypertension)+0.3(Gender)+0.06(Age)+15**

Please let me know if my interpretation of it is right -->

My interpretation: With one unit change in 'Hypertension', log odds of heart disease increases by 2.5 units. Or in other words, a person with hypertension is 2.5 times more likely to get heart disease as compared to a person with no hypertension.

Comment: No, these are not probabilities or odds, these are log odds, you have to transform this.

Comment: What is it that I need to transform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpreting log odds in case of multiple predictor variables](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/113175/interpreting-log-odds-in-case-of-multiple-predictor-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I be wrong, but I do not think 2.5 times more. Considering you are not measuring the probability of heart disease to non-hypertension. On this way, your first sentence is correct, but the second, do not.

Comment: Thank you for the to-the-point answer.